# How to Add caching to the AWS KMS Using PHP

Tags: php, encryption, amazon-kms

I have an application sing **PHP** that have many sensitive data , so I'm locking to protect this data by encrypt and decrypt  using **AWS KMS**.

i'm using below code to encrypt :

```
 $kmsObj = $kms->encrypt(array('KeyId' => "alias/$alias",'Plaintext' => $string));
```

And below code to decrypt :

```
$decrypt = $kms->decrypt(array('CiphertextBlob' => base64_decode($string)));
```

But I have an issue that on each customer request I have to call KMS more than 10 times to encrypt/decrypt the data or to get the data key .

Are there any solution to do the encrypt/decrypt data using shared key on my application by calling KMS just one time to get the data key and then use the encrypt/decrypt others data using PHP to reduce number of calls to the **KMS**

Comment: You could put all of the input into an array, then encrypt.

Comment: What type of input I have to put in order to do the cache